# How to run a command every tie I open Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu

How could I make it so that when I open the terminal, it executes the neofetch command to show my computer statistics?

Answer (score 0):

It is not trivial to tie this to the terminal, but it easy to tie it to the shell: Just put it into `.profile` or `.bashrc`